# ARC weak reference in a C callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm currently playing with AudioQueue services, and I have a small problem.

The AudioQueue has a bunch of callbacks, each of which can carry a "user data", a pointer basically. I wish I could pass one of my objects as this pointer.

So what happens is that, on certain occasions, the AudioQueue is calling my callback in a way close to this:

```
static void HandleOutputBuffer (
    void                *aqData,
    AudioQueueRef       inAQ,
    AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer
) {
    MyPlayerData *mpd = (MyPlayerData *)aqData;
    ...
}
```

This usually works good, but when my player reaches the end of the media, it is deallocated. But often times the callback `HandleOutputBuffer` is called after the `MyPlayerData` object is deallocated, resulting in a nice segfault.

I wish I could use a weak reference for this. Is there any way I could have an ARC `void *` pointer? Something that would be set to nil whenever the object is deallocated?

I'm currently looking at `__weak`, but I'm not sure this is the right tool to use...

Comment: Is `MyPlayerData` not an objective c object? Why does it have to be `void*`? Wouldn't `id` be ok to use? Can you show the code where you call `HandleOutputBuffer` (as the problem is that when you do that call, aqData has been deallocated already)

Comment: I'm not responsible for calling this `HandleOutputBuffer`, as this is a callback called by the AudioQueue whenever an audio buffer is free to use (i.e. it has been played). I therefore don't have control on this, nor may I change the signature of the method.

Comment: Oh right, then no, there's no way ARC can manage that for you. You'll have to come up with a mechanism that will ensure the situation never occurs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ARC cannot manage a `void *` reference to an object and set it to `NULL` if the object is
deallocated.

You have two different options when creating the context pointer from the object pointer:

- `const void *context = (__bridge void *)mpd;`

  This is what you do now. In this case, *you* have to ensure that the object exists
  as long as the audio queue uses it in the callback.
- `const void *context = (__bridge_retained void *)mpd;`

  This *increases* the retain count of the object, so that the object is "kept alive",
  i.e. it will not be deallocated.
  In this case, you have to release this reference eventually when it is no longer needed,
  with `CFRelease(context)`.

Reference: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts